# getting the value from a column in a stored procedure via select statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get a path of a document which i have stored in a stored procedure. I am calling the stored procedure and passing in the proper parameters and i want to select the storagePath column from that stored procedure and assign it to a string. Any idea to what i am doing wrong what be great to point out.

This is what i have and when i debug i don't see: "../../TestFile":

```
string storagePath = stuSubSvc.RetrieveInformation(elementId, submission)
  .Select(s => s.StoragePath)
  .ToString();
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question, and I'm concerned your question would be too specific to be of general interest.

Comment: @neontapir i want to know the proper way to extract info from column in a stored procedure

Comment: For example, what do you see when you run the code you've shown, if you aren't seeing TestFile? Is the data in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string storagePath = stuSubSvc.RetrieveInformation(elementId, submission)
  .Select(s => s.StoragePath).SingleOrDefault();
```